# kexec -l then kexec -e will enter into the 2nd kernel successfully, but kexec -p then crash will fail and stuck

Tags: linux-kernel

As the title describes, kexec -l then kexec -e will enter into the 2nd kernel successfully, but kexec -p then crash will fail and stuck when I try to setup kdump and kexec on my laptop (Linux will-ThinkPad-L470 4.13.0-rc5 #3 SMP PREEMPT Wed Aug 23 16:11:24 CST 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux). The commands are:

```
kexec -p /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-rc5 --initrd=/boot/initrd.img-4.13.0-rc5 -d --reuse-cmdline
```

Then, if I echo c > /proc/sysrq-trigger, the machine will panic and stuck.
But the kexec -l will success.

```
kexec -l /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-rc5 --initrd=/boot/initrd.img-4.13.0-rc5 -d --reuse-cmdline --append="will"
kexec -e
```

Then I will get the "will" in the /proc/cmdline of the 2nd kernel.

Does anyone have idea about this ?

Comment: Don't you have to use `-p` together with `-l`? I.e. `kexec -p -l /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-rc5 --initrd=/boot/initrd.img-4.13.0-rc5 -d --reuse-cmdline --append="will"; echo c > /proc/sysrq-trigger`.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get your point. Why use -p and -l together ? These two parameters are used for different usages. Even if I use them together, the result should be equal to "-p" as  the source code of kexec.

Comment: I'm going off the [man pages for kexec](https://linux.die.net/man/8/kexec). `-l (--load) kernel` vs `-p (--load-panic)`. I might be reading it wrong but it doesn't look like `-p` takes a _kernel_ parameter?

Comment: According to the kexec source code,  "--resuse-cmdline" will let the kexec 
 read the /proc/cmdline to get the current kernel command line parameters as the new one to the 2nd kernel, "--append" will add the parameter which it carries to the new command line parameters, most important is that, the kexec -p will add a new kernel command line parameter "elfcorehdr" into the new kernel command line parameters which indicates the 2nd kernel to export the /proc/vmcore.

Comment: I'm not disputing any of what you said. All I'm saying is that it doesn't look like you're actually _loading_ a kernel when you do `kexec -p /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-rc5 [...]`. Are you certain that `kexec -l /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-rc5 -p [...]` doesn't work?

Comment: kexec -p will load the kernel as well as the '-l' option.